# Trying to perform a cartesian product on two XML files using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db

I'm trying to work with XML datasets, and I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to perform iterations and join operations with XQuery.

I have these two XML tables:

employees.xml:

```
<employees>
    
    <employee cod="E01" dept="D01">
        <name>John</name>
        <middle-name>S.</middle-name>
        <lastname>Gladstone</lastname>
    </employee>
    
    <employee cod="E02" dept="D01">
        <name>Ana</name>
        <lastname>Ferraz</lastname>
    </employee>

</employees>
```

and departments.xml:

```
<departments>

    <department cod="D01">
        <name>Sales</name>
        <local>3rd floor</local>
    </department>
    
    <department cod="D02">
        <name>Finances</name>
        <local>4th floor</local>
    </department>
    
</departments>
```

I want to perform a join operation on this data, resulting in something like this:

```
<result>
    <dep-emp>
        <department>Sales</department>
        <employee>John</employee>
    </dep-emp>
    
    <dep-emp>
        <department>Sales</department>
        <employee>Ana</employee>
    </dep-emp>
    
    <dep-emp>
        <department>Finances</department>
        <employee>John</employee>
    </dep-emp>
    
    <dep-emp>
        <department>Finances</department>
        <employee>Ana</employee>
    </dep-emp>
</result>
```

I have tried to use a "for" statement with no success. Can someone please help me?

Comment: So although in your first sample each `employee` seems to be tied to a department through the `dept` attribute, in your result you just want to create a new `dep-emp` element for each existing `department` in the second sample and each `employee` from the first? Can you show us what you have tried and how it failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty straight forward embedded loop:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $employees := <employees>
    <employee cod="E01" dept="D01">
        <name>John</name>
        <middle-name>S.</middle-name>
        <lastname>Gladstone</lastname>
    </employee>
    <employee cod="E02" dept="D01">
        <name>Ana</name>
        <lastname>Ferraz</lastname>
    </employee>
</employees>

let $departments := <departments>
    <department cod="D01">
        <name>Sales</name>
        <local>3rd floor</local>
    </department>
    
    <department cod="D02">
        <name>Finances</name>
        <local>4th floor</local>
    </department>
</departments>

return <result>{
    for $dep in $departments/department
        for $emp in $employees/employee[@dept eq $dep/@cod]
            return <dep-emp>
                <department>{string($dep/name)}</department>
                <employee>{string($emp/name)}</employee>
            </dep-emp>
}</result>
```